# MS Access - GUID

Tags: ms-access, guid

I have an MS Access table with employee data (including user IDs) that is appended once a month. Every month I add the data of the respective month that contains almost everyone from previous month but also net new records

**Question:**

How do I create a "recurring" GUID for each employee? In other words - if an employee is part of multiple month's data this employee should always have the same GUID while net-new employees should have a net-new GUID

This is exactly how it works with the existing user id - just want to replace that by GUID for privacy reason.
Thanks for your help in advance
Markus

Comment: Create and maintain a persistent table mapping user IDs to GUIDs.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this task? If so, please mark as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Create a table with two fields:

```
UserGuid: AutoNumber. Field Size: Replication ID
UserID:   Field type (and size): As your current User ID.
```

Now, whenever a User Id is entered in the table, a Guid is created.

Then, when needed, look up the Guid using the User ID